# Accessing API handling node in express ejs front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I've set up a working, very simple express server with ejs as my view engine.

My web page has a form, and with the press of an html button the input is turned into the json object `userFormData`. I have another node.js file that handles interactions with an API. On this file, I have a function `createNewFromUserFormData(userFormData)`. I now wonder what the best way would be to get my userFormData from the front end, to the API handling js node on the back end. Is there any way I can call a function on the node from the frontend index.ejs in the view folder?

Basically my question is just: How can I export json from the webapp to a node server? Is there any way I can call a function on the backend from a `onclick` on the index.ejs?

Answer (score 0):

*EJS* (Embedded JavaScript) is a template engine using vanilla *JavaScript* which will result in static *HTML* document (or partials).

Handling any events (Network, user...) would go into the *HTML* document embedded `script`s.

You should be able to attach an event handler as the `onclick` function calling your backend API (with whatever content you should send along as request payload).

Below is an example of a simple *EJS* template file using vanilla *JavaScript* to register a `click` event handler which `fetch`es a remote API (which should be your internal route endpoint) to display its result:

```
<span id='link'>
    <% if (true) { %>
        <%= 'Guess what to do?' %>
      <% } %>
</span>
<p id="activity"></p>

<script>
    const linkNode = document.querySelector('#link');
    linkNode.addEventListener('click', () => {
        fetch('https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity')
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((res) => {
                const textNode = document.querySelector('#activity');
                textNode.textContent = res.activity;
            });
    });
</script>
```